# Resistance of Electrolytes

Tags: electrochemistry, ions

During electrochemical experiments, we consider the resistance of the electrolytes. What exactly is causing the electrolytes to offer resistance to flow of charges in them? Also, does the resistance also depends on the electrodes we use?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75954/conductivity-of-water-and-chlorine/75959#75959

Comment: Ya it's good and answers my question.